# Unit Testing Visual Studio Online Selenium ChromeDriver Exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium ChromeDriver in a Unit Test project to test some action on a web page ...

`var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
 chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");`

Chrome driver has been installed from nuget

`Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver -Version 2.28.0`.

When build my project in Visual Studio Online I receive some error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520

Any solution to solve this?

Comment: Add the chromedriver.exe to the bin folder of your project.

Comment: Do you add Nuget Installer step to restore the package? Can you share the detail build log here?

Comment: Do you have the current version of Chrome installed on that computer?

Comment: yes, but problem are not on my pc.... on visual studio online - builds

Comment: Do you use on premise build agent? Can you build and run test on that machine manually? (The Chrome is not available in Hosted agent and Hosted agent is running as service that can't do interactive test)

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the command line to install things for NuGet, I use the menu option in VS.

1. Open VS and click on your project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Click on Project > Manage NuGet Packages... from the menu,

See what shows as installed here and if there are any updates. You might try uninstalling and reinstall via the menu I described above and see if it helps. I use NuGet as described all the time and don't have this issue.

Comment: I added from nuget selenium driver and still get this error

System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error:

 cannot find Chrome binary
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520

Answer (score 1):

ChromeDriver cannot find the Chrome binary files just as the error message indicates. Please check and make sure that Chrome Browser is installed on the build agent or test machine which run the test.

Answer (score 0):

In general chrome will be installed in the path - C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

So please check for installation path. If chrome is not in that path then uninstall old one and install chrome using link - http://filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/

The below Nuget packages should be installed

1. selenium.webdriver
2. selenium.webdriver.chromedriver

The below code will open chrome and navigate to google page

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't set the path of chromedriver binary in System PATH variable, this how you can do it in code. Do it before you initialize the driver object.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

Comment: "/path/to/chromedriver" from my pc or to folder in my UntiTest Project?

Comment: You don't need to do this when you install drivers via NuGet. Mine work just fine with no properties set and I've used NuGet.